# how to make CSS compatible with ie7 and other versions of internet explorer

Tags: html, css

the following CSS is fully compatible with the ie8 but when i switch the mode to ie7 the css is not working properly.the height of the div gets bigger in ie7 and the list in div is not shown properly ...please help me.......here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xAE9n/

```
.wrap {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}

.accordion1 {
    width: 178px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

    .accordion1 h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
        color: #333;

        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .accordion1 li h2 a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

a.active {
    color: white;
}

.accordion1 h2:hover {
    background:orange;
    color: white;
}

.accordion1 li div.content {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #fcfbfb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
}

.accordion1 li:hover h2 {
    color: white !important;
    background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
    background:orange
}

    .accordion1 li:hover h2 a {
        color: white !important;
    }

.accord > li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

    .accord > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-left: 12px;
        color: #5f5c5c;
        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_pointer_se.gif") 0.002em no-repeat;
    }

    .accord > li > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #5f5c5c;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_dirmini_orange_e.gif") 0.35em no-repeat;
        padding-left: 17px;
    }

    .accord > li > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1px;
    }

.accord {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

    .accord > li > a:hover {
        color: #f8b106;
    }

    .accord > li > ul > li > a:hover {
        color: #f8b106;
    }

.accordion1 > li > h2.active {
    color: white;
    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
}

    .accordion1 > li > h2.active a {
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: "some other issues also" - If you want answers for them, I suggest you tell us what issues you are facing. I'm not going to test your code in the browsers to determine what's wrong.

Comment: @FDL i have edit my question u can see and give me appropriate ans

Answer (score 1):

[www.browserhacks.com](http://www.browserhacks.com)

You can use .selector\ {} (notice the backslash) which will only be visible in IE7.

Example:

```
.className\ { color: #000; }
hr\ { color: #fff }
```

Alternatively, you may want to make an IE7 specific stylesheet. Pasting this into the head section of your website will achieve this.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some steps to fix your IE7 problems:

1. Compare carefully the result in IE7 and IE8.
2. Identify, one by one, all the issues you have
3. Search in google about the specific problem you try to fix (just an example: "IE7 height bigger css").
4. Try to fix it
5. If nothing works, ask a question here about that specific issue, with an example if you can, and the efforts you did to fix it.